# Xero oauth 1.0 convert to 2.0

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, xero-api

We are using OAuth1.0 for xero and now we have to change this to 2.0. 
To do the migration what is the first most step?
Is there any code changes to existing application? We are using c# mvc

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [Xero C# SDK for OAuth2.0](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard/tree/oauth2) although you could also plug in any standard OAuth2.0 or OpenID Connect library.